# Is it possible to use HAL functions for I2C communication with a MLX90395 magnetometer on STM32F4 with a repeated start condition?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, i2c, stm32cubeide

I am currently trying to program the magnetometer MLX90395 with the STM32F446RE microcontroller using the I2C protocol.

I am making use of the HAL functions (Master_Transmit/Receive, Mem_Write/Read) and I have see that they always put a stop condition after the initial 2 bytes (DeviceAddress and Register).

[STM Logic - Stop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj7pt.png)

In the datasheet for the sensor it is explicitly mentioned that a repeated start is required, since a stop condition can effect e.g. register values, state of sensor, etc.

[MLX requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mEil.png)

I looked at the demo Arduino sketch for this magnetometer and it indeed uses a repeated start.

[Arduino Logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKhEY.png)

Is there a solution or a workaround for this?

I tried changing between Master functions and Mem- functions, but did not witness any change. The same functions but _IT() may be an option, but I do not fully comprehend their way of work.

Here is an example function that puts the IC into single measurement mode:

```
enumExit Enter_SM_Mode(uint8_t address, uint8_t cmd_reg){



   HAL_StatusTypeDef ret;



   //-----------------------Send the status byte to command/ status register 0x80

   static uint8_t st_sm_mode = 0b00111010;//start single measurement byte



   ret = HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, (uint16_t)(address), cmd_reg, sizeof(cmd_reg), &st_sm_mode, 1, 100);

   if(ret != HAL_OK)

   {

         return EXIT_BAD_ERROR;

   }



   //--------------Receive status byte------------------/

   uint8_t status_data[2];

   /*Following 3 line: Device address manipulation

   * in order to READ*/

   uint8_t address16_R;

   address16_R = address;

   address16_R |= 0x01;



   ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, (uint16_t)address16_R, status_data, 1, 50);

   if(ret != HAL_OK)

   {

         return EXIT_BAD_ERROR;

   }



   return EXIT_OK;

}
```

Comment: `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit/Received()` do not do a repeat start so don't use those.  But `HAL_I2C_Mem_Read/Write()` should do a repeat start.  Show your code with `HAL_I2C_Mem_Read/Write()` so we can if how you're using them.

Comment: I added it to the question

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you're trying to do from that code.

The first call to `HAL_I2C_Mem_Write()` *writes* the value `st_sm_mode` to memory-address `cmd_reg` of the device at device-address `address`.  When you examine the I2C signals you should see a repeat start between writing the memory-address and *writing* the value.  Is that what you're trying to do?  There are no commands in the MLX90395 datasheet that *write* data to an memory-address.  They mostly *read* data from a memory-address so I'm skeptical that writing is what you want.

The next call to `HAL_I2C_Master_Receive()` attempts to read a value from the device but it doesn't specify any memory-address within the device.  This call won't write a memory-address and it won't send a repeat start.  There are no commands in the MLX90395 datasheet that begin by directly reading data so this is probably an unsupported command.  All the commands in the data sheet begin by writing a memory-address.

To read a value from a memory-address you need to use only `HAL_I2C_Mem_Read()`.  It writes the memory-address, sends the repeat start, and then reads the data from that memory-address.

You can use `HAL_I2C_Mem_Read()` to implement the MLX90395 "RR" command like this:

```
// The MLX90395 datasheet says this left shift is necessary
// for the RR command.
uint16_t memory_address = register_num << 1;
uint8_t data[2];
    
HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, device_address, memory_address,
                 I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, data, 2, timeout);
```